# Autopublish content from drupal to wordpress

Tags: nodes

My question is that i am having a drupal blog and wordpress on different different domains. I am looking for a module so that whenever i publish some content in drupal it should also published in wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Wordpress question, but on drupal side you could expose the new content with a feed or JSON View and after that use some WP module to import the data.

**Edit**
And here's something that you can use on WP side to autopost from a feed: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/